# Why am I getting complex results when I evaluate may integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider

```
(1/h)*Integrate[-Log[Abs[Cos[x]]], {x, 0, h}]
```

This integral should be real-valued.

P.S. The result I receive is

> ```
> (-I/2)*h + (((47*I)/24)*Pi^2)/h + Log[1 + E^((2*I)*h)] - Log[Cos[h]^2]/2 - ((I/2)*PolyLog[2, -E^((2*I)*h)])/h
> ```

It can be verified to be non-real by building its plot using `ReImPlot` function.

Comment: Please make the question complete: what is the output and does it check out numerically when you substitute real values for `a` and `h`?

Comment: 1. Those integrals are not the same as what you mentioned in your questions. 2. The value of these integrals is not real (Sec and Cos go negative). The result is easily verified as correct by numerical comparison. 3. You did not answer address the first comment. I let that integral run for 10 minutes, and since it hasn't finished in that time, I aborted it. I doubt that many people will wait longer.

Comment: @Szabolcs I added the result I received to the question.

Comment: Not an answer, but a comment: Using Mma 12 I have obtained another expression: `ConditionalExpression[expr, C[1] \[Element] Integers && 2 h + \[Pi] >= 4 \[Pi] C[1] && C[1] >= 1]` , where `expr` is the expression you gave. If one adds to the `Integrate` statement such a condition, say, `h>3Pi/2`, one comes to a result in real numbers. Nevertheless, this is still unclear to me, since `NIntegrate[-Log[Abs[Cos[x]]], {x, 0, 1}]` returns a real result independently of any condition.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the real part of the OP's result is the desired solution, but the problem `Integrate` has presumably comes from the periodic singularities.  The integral is clearly real for `Pi/2 < h < Pi/2` because `Abs[Cos[x]] >= 0` and the integrand is real except when `Cos[x] == 0`. Further the singularities are logarithmic, and therefore the integral is convergent even when `h` is outside the interval.

The boundary conditions at each discontinuity between `0` and `h` need to be reconciled.  Since `h` is indeterminate, this is a task `Integrate` seems unprepared to handle.  Neither will `DSolve`, which gives some hints about the trouble it encounters:

> ```
> DSolve::pcju: Unable to detect the jumps in the piecewise differential equation. 
> The solution may be discontinuous.
>
> DSolve::bvnr: For some branches of the general solution, the given boundary 
> conditions do not restrict the existing freedom in the general solution.
>
> DSolve::bvsing: Unable to resolve some of the arbitrary constants in the general 
> solution using the given boundary conditions. It is possible that some of the 
> conditions have been specified at a singular point for the equation.
> ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Looking at the plot of the OP's integral, we see that the imaginary part has derivative `0` and jumps at the singularities of the integrand.  It suggests that the real part is probably the solution.

```
op = (-I/2)*h + (((47*I)/24)*Pi^2)/h + Log[1 + E^((2*I)*h)] - 
   Log[Cos[h]^2]/2 - ((I/2)*PolyLog[2, -E^((2*I)*h)])/h;
intop = h*op; (* the OP divided the integral by h *)

ReImPlot[intop, {h, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Let's test it.  The derivative of the real part can be compared to the integrand, assuming `h` is real.  `Re` and `Im` are not differentiable (in *Mathematica*, which computes the complex derivative), but it's easy enough to manually intervene:

```
intop = intop // Re // ComplexExpand // Simplify
(*  1/2 (Im[PolyLog[2, -E^(2 I h)]] + h Log[4])  *)

(* derivative: *)
dintop = 1/2 (Im[D[PolyLog[2, -E^(2 I h)], h]] + Log[4])
(*  1/2 (Log[4] - 2 Re[Log[1 + E^(2 I h)]])  *)

(* difference of derivative and integrand: *)
dintop - (-Log@Abs@Cos[h]) // ComplexExpand // 
 Simplify[#, x ∈ Reals] &
(*  0  *)
```

So the derivative of `Re[h * op]` is equal to the integrand. And at `h = 0`, `intop = 0`. Therefore, `intop/h` is the solution.

Comment: When the singularity is a pole, I am prepared for imaginable jumps but why are there such jumps when the singularities are logarithmic?!!!

Comment: @Anixx When the integral is indefinite and the number of singularities over the whole domain is infinite, it might be solvable only in special cases. In this case, the integrand is periodic, which makes the problem reducible to a finite one, but maybe that special case is not handled. When you give it a finite problem, like `Integrate[-Log[Abs[Cos[x]]], {x, 0, 20}]`, you get back the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica 12 does finally get it right if we make proper assumptions.  When I evaluate the integral, assuming $h > 0$, it returns a result valid only for $h\geq \frac{3\pi }{2}$.  To get the whole range, we have to evaluate each range separately:

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions =.

fn1[h_] = 
 Assuming[0 <= h <= π/2, (1/h)*Integrate[-Log[Abs[Cos[x]]], {x, 0, h}]];

fn2[h_] = 
 Assuming[π/2 < h <= 3 π/2, (1/h)*Integrate[-Log[Abs[Cos[x]]], {x, 0, h}]];

fn3[h_] = 
 Simplify[Assuming[h > 0, (1/h)*Integrate[-Log[Abs[Cos[x]]], {x, 0, h}]] /. 
   C[1] -> 1, h >= 3 π/2];
```

I did the last integral that way because merely assuming $h > 3 \pi/2$ did not work.

Plot the integral vs h.

```
p1 = Plot[Evaluate[fn1[h]] // FullSimplify, {h, 0, π/2}];

p2 = Plot[Evaluate[fn2[h]] // FullSimplify, {h, π/2, 3 π/2}];

p3 = Plot[Evaluate[fn3[h]] // FullSimplify, {h, 3 π/2, 10}];

Show[{p1, p2, p3}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Negative h values give a mirror image of the positive h values.

FWIW, Mathematica 8 does not make us jump through as many hoops.  It gives a result covering the full range for $h > 0$.  I have noticed in many situations that many more assumptions are required to get results from later versions of Mathematica.